# How to Save Contact form 7 Shortcode to wp_options database

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7, wordpress-shortcode

I'm building a custom wordpress plugin that will display contactform7 form on the homepage.

Workflow :

> 1.User create the form using contactform7 and copy the shortcode
>
> 2.Users input the value/shortcode on the plugin's setting form
>
> 3.Plugin capture the value/shortcode using $_POST['the-shortcode']
>
> 4.Plugin save the value/shortcode on wp_options database
>
> 5.Plugin echo out or do_shortcode to display the values/shortcode/CF7 form

**My problem : 
whenever I save the contact form 7 shortcode 
via the plugin's setting form**

> [contact-form-7 id="4" title="Contact form 1"]

it become like this : (notice there are some \ )

> [contact-form-7 id=\"4\" title=\"Contact form 1\"]

I tried to use esc_attr() but it did not work.

> esc_attr($_POST['the-shortcode'])

**How to save contact form 7 shortcode just as it is 
to the wp_options database so I can echo do_shortcode('theshortcode') ?**

**This is the code for the plugin's setting form :**

```html
<?php

global $options;
$cform_shortcode = esc_attr($_POST['cform_shortcode']);
$options['cform_shortcode'] = $cform_shortcode;
update_option('plugin_databasename_db', $options);
$options = get_option('plugin_databasename_db');
$cform_shortcode = $options['cform_shortcode'];
?>

<table>
    <tr>
    <td scope="row"><label for="tablecell">
    Contact Form ShortCode
    </label></td>
    <td scope="row"><label for="tablecell">
    <textarea name="cform_shortcode" id="" cols="80" rows="3"><?php if (isset($cform_shortcode)) {echo $cform_shortcode;} else {'';} ?></textarea>
    </label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**This is the code for the front end:**

```html
<?php 
global $options; 
$options = get_option('plugin_databasename_db');

if ( isset( $options['cform_title'] ) && isset( $options['cform_shortcode'] ) ){ ?>
<p class="wpic-strong"><?php echo $options['cform_title']?></p>
<div class="list-group-item-video">
  <?php echo do_shortcode($options['cform_shortcode']); ?>
</div>
<br/>
<?php 
} else {
'';
}   
?>
```

Comment: This should work, but you haven't provided enough info to troubleshoot.  Where's your code showing how you save the shortcode to the options table? And where you load it back from the options table?

Comment: @cale_b Thanks for responding. Please see the code above. just added it.

Comment: The shortcode must be wrapped in square braces, even inside the `do_shortcode` function.  So - the answer is `do_shortcode('[' . stripslashes($options['cform_shortcode']) . ']');`

Comment: @cale_b... Thanks for taking time on this, really appreciate it. I tried your code and it returns --> [contact-form-7 id=\"4\" title=\"Contact form 1\"]. So i stick with the other one that works.Again thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Temporarily replace this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode($options['cform_shortcode']);   ?>
```

with this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="4" title="Contact form 1"]');  ?>
```

Just to see if it works (that way).

[Edit]
The saved value may contain `\`, so try this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( wp_unslash($options['cform_shortcode']) ); ?>
```

[Edit #2]
In that case (i.e. the `&quot;` thing), it's because you used the `esc_attr` function when you saved the user's input into the database.

So use `sanitize_text_field` (which strips out HTML tags) instead of `esc_attr` (which doesn't strip HTML tags, but converts them to HTML entities):

```
$cform_shortcode = sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash($_POST['cform_shortcode']) );
```

And then re-save the options (i.e. the Contact Form 7 Shortcode) via the back-end form. After that, see if the `do_shortcode` thing works on the front-end.

Comment: This one works.
<?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="4" title="Contact form 1"]'); ?>

Comment: That might not solve the problem, but it's worth trying.. Can you share the output of `var_dump($options['cform_shortcode'])`?

Comment: I appreciate your help. The var_dump result is --> string(66) "[contact-form-7 id="4" title="Contact form 1"]"

Comment: Note:this is really weird. the shortcode is exactly the same on the var_dump() but it return as "[contact-form-7 404 "Not Found"]" when I echo do_shortcode($options['cform_shortcode']). I checked the wp_options database, here's what it saved on the database --> s:66:"[contact-form-7 id=&quot;4&quot; title=&quot;Contact form 1&quot;]"

Comment: Thank you sooo much for your help. I really appreciate it. Yes sanitize_text_field solved the problem. The shortcode works and the contact form is now visible.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, and I actually also learned some good things from what we've gone through on this question. So thanks to you too!

Comment: @Sally - your opening sentence in this answer has two problems: 1) IT's not necessary, and 2) It's incorrect, as it mentions "answer above" - answers "move" up and down based on votes, whether accepted or not, etc - so when referencing another answer, its recommend to get the link (the small, gray, "Share" button in the lower left of your answer will give you the link)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @cale_b!